# MySQL 5.7.17 running on Linux Mint (can't start mysqld_safe --skip-grant-privileges

Tags: linux-mint, mysql5

Accidentally erased MySQL 5.7.17 (linux) privileges for root.  I can still login as root.  Just can't do much.  I've searched web for days looking for way to start mysql_safe --skip-grant-privileges  but none of the suggestions work.

An article in MySQL doc suggested a different path that has replaced `mysql_safe`.  Looks very complicated, and I can't risk screwing up my system with yet another thing that didn't work.

I have about a week and then need to have the system working again.  Wondering if I can delete MySQL and do a fresh install would the tables be accessible by the fresh installation?

Comment: You can use MySQL configuration file to do that. Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables. Well explained how to do what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

B.5.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems

On Unix, use the following procedure to reset the password for the MySQL 'root'@'localhost' account. To change the password for a root account with a different host name part, modify the instructions to use that host name.

The instructions assume that you will start the MySQL server from the Unix login account that you normally use for running it. For example, if you run the server using the mysql login account, you should log in as mysql before using the instructions. Alternatively, you can log in as root, but in this case you must start mysqld with the `--user=mysql` option. If you start the server as root without using `--user=mysql`, the server may create root-owned files in the data directory, such as log files, and these may cause permission-related problems for future server startups. If that happens, you will need to either change the ownership of the files to mysql or remove them.

```
Log on to your system as the Unix user that the MySQL server runs as (for example, mysql).

Stop the MySQL server if it is running. Locate the .pid file that contains the server's process ID. The exact location and name of this file depend on your distribution, host name, and configuration. Common locations are /var/lib/mysql/, /var/run/mysqld/, and /usr/local/mysql/data/. Generally, the file name has an extension of .pid and begins with either mysqld or your system's host name.

Stop the MySQL server by sending a normal kill (not kill -9) to the mysqld process. Use the actual path name of the .pid file in the following command:

shell> kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`
```

Use backticks (not forward quotation marks) with the cat command. These cause the output of cat to be substituted into the kill command.

Create a text file containing the password-assignment statement on a single line. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

Save the file. This example assumes that you name the file /home/me/mysql-init. The file contains the password, so do not save it where it can be read by other users. If you are not logged in as mysql (the user the server runs as), make sure that the file has permissions that permit mysql to read it.

Start the MySQL server with the special --init-file option:

```
shell> mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```

The server executes the contents of the file named by the `--init-file` option at startup, changing the 'root'@'localhost' account password.

Other options may be necessary as well, depending on how you normally start your server. For example, `--defaults-file` may be needed before `--init-file`.

```
After the server has started successfully, delete /home/me/mysql-init.
```

You should now be able to connect to the MySQL server as root using the new password. Stop the server and restart it normally.

If the ALTER USER statement fails to reset the password, try repeating the procedure using the following statements to modify the user table directly:

```
UPDATE mysql.user
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

B.5.3.2.3 Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions

The preceding sections provide password-resetting instructions specifically for Windows and Unix and Unix-like systems. Alternatively, on any platform, you can reset the password using the mysql client (but this approach is less secure):

```
Stop the MySQL server if necessary, then restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges, and disables account-management statements such as ALTER USER and SET PASSWORD. Because this is insecure, you might want to use --skip-grant-tables in conjunction with --skip-networking to prevent remote clients from connecting.

Connect to the MySQL server using the mysql client; no password is necessary because the server was started with --skip-grant-tables:

shell> mysql
```

In the mysql client, tell the server to reload the grant tables so that account-management statements work:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then change the 'root'@'localhost' account password. Replace the password with the password that you want to use. To change the password for a root account with a different host name part, modify the instructions to use that host name.

MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

You should now be able to connect to the MySQL server as root using the new password. Stop the server and restart it normally (without the --skip-grant-tables and `--skip-networking` options).

If the ALTER USER statement fails to reset the password, try repeating the procedure using the following statements to modify the user table directly:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

PREV   HOME   UP   NEXT

Comment: Took too long to find this answer... I logged into more than 4 different MySQL manuals pro porting to be version 5.7.x  none had searches that came up with responses to --skip-grant-privileges.  This is ridiculous.  However Oracle seems to revel in the confusion of users who don't pay their way.